# How can I reduce the no of IFs

Tags: c#

How can I reduce the no of IF statements and rewrite the same efficiently.

Name is dynamic. Name could be "One hundred" or "one thousand". It can "Two hundred" or "Two thousand". I want it to enter the respective IF if Name contains the word 'one' or 'two'.

ID and Name contain same string. ID will also hold "One hundred" or "one thousand"...

```
         if (Name.Contains("One"))
         {
             var checkIndex = Chart.YAxis.FindIndex(f => f.Index == index &&  f.Id.Contains("One"));                  
             axisIndex = AddAxis(checkIndex, axis);               
         }
         else if (Name.Contains("Two"))
         {
             var checkIndex = Chart.YAxis.FindIndex(f => f.Index == index && f.Id.Contains("Two"));
             axisIndex = AddAxis(checkAxisIndex, axis);
         }
         else if (Name.Contains("Three"))
         {
             var checkIndex = Chart.YAxis.FindIndex(f => f.Index == index && f.Id.Contains("Three"));
             axisIndex = AddAxis(checkAxisIndex, axis);
         }
         .....
         else     
         {
            ....
         }
```

Thank you.

Comment: It looks like each `if` block is doing *almost* the same thing, except some of them are referencing a variable called `checkAxisIndex` which isn't defined anywhere in this code (and are never using a variable they do locally define).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use an approach like this :

```
var possibleNames = new []{"One", "Two", "Three", "Four"};
var selectedName = possibleNames.FirstOrDefault(n=> Name.Contains(n));

if(string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(selectedName)) // return or throw

var index = Chart.YAxis.FindIndex(f => f.Index == index && f.Id.Contains(selectedName));
axisIndex = AddAxis(index , axis)
```

Comment: Slightly shorter using method group syntax `possibleNames.FirstOrDefault(Name.Contains);`

Answer (score 0):

I'd try to parse the Name field to get the string value. Then the rest should be easy.

```
var value Name.Split(' ')[0];

var index = Chart.YAxis.FindIndex(f => f.Index == index && f.Id.Contains(value));
axisIndex = AddAxis(index , axis);
```

If [String.Split](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.split?view=net-7.0) isn't up to it a [regular expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/regular-expression-language-quick-reference) may be able to get the value you want.